# Static Libraries causing valid heap pointer assertion

Tags: c++, .net, clr

What I have is a project consisting of 3 layers. The base layer is a set of native C++ static libraries, these are core components to a game engine like graphics, audio, etc.

The middle layer groups all of these together into another static library which is the engine itself. The reason for this is because I wanted the engine to be compiled into an executeable for distribution but also so that it can be included into the top most layer.

The top layer is a .net application designed for rapidly creating game content. I want to distribute the Studio for free and the engine.exe for commercial use. Hence why I want to create the engine into a library.

Somewhere along the way a bug is getting through the compilation stage. The engine.exe works fine, however the .net application breaks when I add:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

The program gets through the compilation stage with no errors but then explodes before it gets to the first breakpoint, in fact it doesn't even get to the main function from what I can tell. Either it optimizes it out or something else. The error I get is a debug assertion _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData). It is on line 1516 of dbgheap.c. I know thats not the problem but I'm hoping someone recognises the assertion and could help.

My best bet is that the problem is something to do with how I'm linking the libraries and also the compiler settings, I've tried different settings, haven't removed the problem yet. If anyone has any experience with this that would be great if you need to know more I'll be more than happy to post more information.

Comment: I hope you mean that your adding the `std::string` stuff to the C++ code.

Comment: How exactly do you link the lib to the .NET project? Note that the compilation settings for the compiled DLL and for the application must be *exactly* the same (including compiler version etc.) to assure class sizes, byte alignment etc. are the same.

Comment: Thanks charlie, I'll double check that. I've already tried switching all libraries to /clr are there other settings which would affect it? Which are the ones I need to pay attention to? Everything I know of libs come from a single lab I did at university.

Yes Linuxios, I've narrowed the problem down by including the engine header files one by one. Ones relating to an XML Parser I used seem to cause the problem, thats when I tested std::string on its own with all the other headers commented out.

Thank you for the help thus far :)

Comment: Upon carrying out further experiments, without the engine library linked in the /clr project, but still having the xml parser linked there is no problem.

Somehow the engine library and xml parser library are not compatible in a /clr project. Which is odd and baffles me because they compile and execute in a native .exe just fine. Will post an answer if I get to one, any more suggestions would be greatly appreciated in the meantime.

Comment: @Gigaros -- Any news here?  I have exactly the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works, but an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62db4002-4ebc-4a3a-91ec-9fc702db821e/crtisvalidheappointerpuserdata-why-is-this-code-broken-vs2008?forum=vcgeneral) does the trick.

The solution is to add **__DllMainCRTStartup@12** to the 'Force Symbol References' in Properties | Linker | Input of the C++/ÇLI project that includes the static libraries.